# Java service with multiple child thread

Tags: java, linux

```
ps -ef | grep 426
root      4260   587  0 Apr17 ?        00:00:00 [bnx2i_thread/4]
root      4261   587  0 Apr17 ?        00:00:00 [bnx2i_thread/5]
root      4262   587  0 Apr17 ?        00:00:00 [bnx2i_thread/6]
root      4263   587  0 Apr17 ?        00:00:00 [bnx2i_thread/7]
root      4264   587  0 Apr17 ?        00:00:00 [bnx2i_thread/8]
root      4265   587  0 Apr17 ?        00:00:00 [bnx2i_thread/9]
root      4267   587  0 Apr17 ?        00:00:00 [bnx2i_thread/10]
root      4268   587  0 Apr17 ?        00:00:00 [bnx2i_thread/11]
root      4269   587  0 Apr17 ?        00:00:00 [bnx2i_thread/12]
```

Please help me understand this output of ps command with given pid. I was trying to check if service is running or not.

**Edit:** Apologies for late reply. Use of ps and grep like this is not ideal; although it gives expected results if my application is running. That's how, accidentally I got 'bnx2' network driver which can be in-kernel driver or a seperate package for most 2.6 Linux kernels).

Comment: You should tell why are you using 426 in your command. Do you expect it to be the pid of your process ? Note that grep will show every line with the text 426 on them, not only the lne for pid 426.

Comment: Thanks @DWilches for your helpful correction; you made me research the output i got.

Comment: Thanks @GerritCap for instant solution/suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with java in essence.

Your "service" is launched using a certain application, instead of grepping a process id you can grep the process name

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to find any process associated with java, you should use java keyword.. try the below command:

```
ps -ef | grep -i java
```